# What does this symbol from inside the Kaaba mean?

Tags: kaabah

I was going through a video of inside the Kaaba and came across this symbol. I can partially understand what it says. Any help appreciated.

[image: From inside Kaaba]

[image: From inside the Kaaba]

Comment: Do you have a better picture? To me it looks like the First Kalima in calligraphic style.

Comment: i think  " لا إله إلا الله محمد رسول الله  " is written their !

Comment: "There is no god but God. Muhammad is the messenger of God."

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's the [shahadah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shahada) written in [square Kufic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kufic) calligraphy. Since the image provided is so blurry, here's a clearer version:

[image]
[image]

The colored arrows on the second image indicate the direction it's supposed to be read: Red→Green→Blue→Purple→Orange.

For ease of reading, here's a similar rendering — also square Kufic, although using a different glyph for the ه (ha) — which maps this out in a more legible manner, along with the more common modern Naskh rendering:

[image]

Comment: There is no god but God. Muhammad is the messenger of God.